# how to give multiple images to caffe model

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv, caffe

[using Caffe Framework Models](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d5/de7/tutorial_dnn_googlenet.html#gsc.tab=0).

detect(Image) would give image patches. I would like to pass this image patches to caffe model for recognition . Each Image would give variable number of patches, so I used vector of Mat for patches.

```
vector<Mat> patch = detect(Image);
for(int i = 0; i < patch.size(); i++) {
    resize(patch.at(i), patch.at(i), Size(224, 224));       
    dnn::Blob inputBlob = dnn::Blob(patch.at(i));   
    net.setBlob(".data", inputBlob);   
    net.forward();
    dnn::Blob prob = net.getBlob("prob");
    int classId;
    double classProb;
    getMaxClass(prob, &classId, &classProb);
    std::vector<String> classNames = readClassNames();
    std::cout << "Best class: #" << classId << " '" << classNames.at(classId) << "'" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "Probability: " << classProb* 100 << "%" << std::endl;
}
```

I am facing trouble at `net.forward()` (forward pass to network). I have no issues with creating the network and initializing it by using the  importer. could someone help me with this.

error which I am facing is: OpenCV Error: Assertion failed ((size_t)innerSize * (size_t)numOutputs == blobs[
0].total()) in cv::dnn::FullyConnectedLayer::allocate

Comment: can you be a little more specific regarding "facing trouble"? what error messages do you get?

Comment: please do not post code in comments, edit your post to reflect this error message.

Comment: I got it. my friend trained model which can take 40*40 images as input to model. But in above,the resizing was done at 224*224, hence assertion error.